# Como fazer uma requisição POST passando somente a chave estrangeira e não toda a classe estrangeira? (Entityframeworkcore)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, swagger

Criei três tabelas com relacionamento de foreign key/Chave estrangeira, porém, quando vou fazer o POST, pelo swagger ou pelo postman, não pede somente a chave estrangeira, pede a classe estrangeira toda. Como solucionar isso?

Classe 1:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ApiFIAP.Models
{
    public class ClientModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public string Estado { get; set; }  
        public string Pais { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("id")]
        public Contrato contrato { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Classe 2:

```
{
    public class Contrato
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TipoContrato { get; set; }
        public int AnoInicial { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Classe 3:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ApiFIAP.Models
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ClientModel client { get; set; }
        public string dataType { get; set;}
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
using ApiFIAP.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ApiFIAP.Context
{
    public class cocole:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ClientModel> client { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DataModel> data { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contrato> contrato { get; set; }

        public cocole(DbContextOptions<cocole> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;user id=id_BC;password=Senha_bc;database=postgres");
        }


    }
}
```

Controller Utilizado:

```
using ApiFIAP.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ApiFIAP.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController:ControllerBase
    {

        private cocole cocole;

        public ClientController(cocole coc) 
        {
           cocole = coc;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/client")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> cadastro([FromBody] ClientModel model) 
        {
          cocole.client.Add(model);
            cocole.SaveChangesAsync();

            return Ok("foi");
        }
   }
```

Json Aceito pelo Swagger:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "client": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "estado": "string",
    "pais": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "contrato": {
      "id": 0,
      "tipoContrato": "string",
      "anoInicial": 0
    }
  },
  "dataType": "string",
  "value": "string"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu Controller recebe `ClientModel` (classe) como parâmetro. Isto é observado nesta linha:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> cadastro([FromBody] ClientModel model)
```

Para receber apenas a chave você precisa modificar o parâmetro para um inteiro que podemos chamar de id também:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> cadastro([FromBody] int id)
```

Depois você deve adicionar a lógica para encontrar o item pelo id.

PS: O restante da lógica me pareceu bastante confusa mas não vou me atentar a isto. Mantendo a resposta atendendo à necessidade apresentada na questão.

Comment: me perdoe pela confusão tentei montar um genérico para tentar tirar minha dúvida, neste caso, sendo só um id, como irei conseguir os resto dos dados do client?

Answer (score -2):

A entidade DataModel não sabe qual a foreign key para a entidade ClientModel:

```
public class DataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id")]
    public ClientModel client { get; set; }
    public string dataType { get; set;}
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Olá Diego, muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas mesmo assim a requisição post pede a classe estrangeira inteira. Será que se faz necessário uma Classe DTO?

Comment: Tente criar uma migration para vincular essa alteração informando a FK e atualizar a base de dados com o update-database